# how to read values inside Double quotes

Tags: unix

How to read the values inside the double quotes? e.g.

```
num1            num2
170            "123 456 758"
141            "890 768 134"
546            "890 786 988 678 463"
```

For the above input I want to print the entire values into two parts:
    The number outside the double quotes.
    The number inside the double quotes

```
num2
123 456 758
890 768 134
890 786 988 678 463

num1
170
141
546
```

Can someone help me with a sample code on how to do the above?

Comment: What is num1 num2? Are they fixed strings? The `*` is at the end of the string?

Comment: Between the first and second column there is a tabulator or just spaces? num1 and num2 is fixed or can change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this few trics:

```
awk -F\" '{print $2}' inputfile
```

or

```
cut -d'"' -f2 inputfile
```

or

```
% s='input'
% expr "$s" : '.*"\([^"]*\)"'
```

**This articles also useful :**

1.[UNIX SHELL Quote Tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html)

2.[Unix - Shell Quoting Mechanisms](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-quoting-mechanisms.htm)

Hope, this will useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution. If You specify a little bit more general the input parameters I can present better one. The commented line is an other solution for the same thing.

```
awk 'NR==1 {left[1] = $1; print $2}
NR>1 {left[NR]=$1; sub("^[0-9]+[[:space:]]+\"",""); sub("\"[[:space:]]*$", ""); print}
#NR>1 {left[NR]=$1; if(match($0, "\"[0-9 ]+\"")) $0=substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2); print}
END { print ""; for(i=1;i<=NR;++i) print left[i] }
' <<EOT
num1            num2
170            "123 456 758"
141            "890 768 134"
546            "890 786 988 678 463"
EOT
```

Output:

```
num2
123 456 758
890 768 134
890 786 988 678 463

num1
170
141
546
```